Decrease item quantity if user click on remove item in WooCommerce cart
I am trying to decrease cart item quantity when clicking on the cart item remove link if quantity is greater than one:
function action_woocommerce_remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key, $instance ) {
   
    // print_r($cart_item_key);
    $item = WC()->cart->get_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
    // print_r($item);
    // echo $item['quantity'];
    if($item['quantity'] > 1){
        WC()->cart->set_quantity($cart_item_key, $item['quantity']-1); 
        echo do_shortcode( '[woocommerce_cart]' );
        exit();
    }
};
   
// Add the action
add_action( 'woocommerce_remove_cart_item', 'action_woocommerce_remove_cart_item', 10, 2 );

This way the cart item remove link hook is returning cart page HTML by using do_shortcode('[woocommerce_cart]') so that the final deletion doesn't happen.
But somehow the shorcode is also returning the link with:
<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/courses/cart/?remove_item=2365a4db507862569752334234a29b50&_wpnonce=fd962ed />` 

so if I try changing cart item quantity afterward on the cart page and click on update cart, It's trying to delete again, setting the quantity in the same way.

You need a complete different approach, changing cart item remove link based on quantity, adding some CSS and using some JavaScript (jQuery) code.

When cart item quantity is more than 1, the cart item remove link is replaced with custom HTML (a minus icon) and when clicking on it, the cart item quantity decrease triggering cart update (via JavaScript).
When cart item quantity is equal to 1, the default remove link is displayed (a "x" times icon).

Here is the code:
// Change cart item remove link based on quantity
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', 'change_cart_item_remove_link_based_on_qty', 10, 2 );
function change_cart_item_remove_link_based_on_qty( $remove_link, $cart_item_key ) {
    $cart_item    = WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $cart_item_key ];
    $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
    $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
    $product_name = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
    
    if ( $cart_item['quantity']> 1 ) {
        $remove_link = sprintf(
            '<span class="decrease_qty" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&minus;</span>',
            /* translators: %s is the product name */
            esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Decrease quantity for %s from cart', 'woocommerce' ), wp_strip_all_tags( $product_name ) ) ),
            esc_attr( $product_id ),
            esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
        );
    }
    return $remove_link;
}

// Add Inline CSS and Javascript to cart page
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents', 'add_cart_inline_css_and_js', 10, 2 );
function add_cart_inline_css_and_js() {
    // CSS
    ?><style>
    span.decrease_qty {
        display: block;
        width: 1.618em;
        height: 1.618em;
        line-height: 1.618;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }
    span.decrease_qty::before {
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor:pointer;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1;
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        font-weight: 900;
        line-height: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        color: #737781;
        line-height: 1.618;
        text-indent: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    table.cart td.product-remove span.decrease_qty {
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 1.41575em;
        top: -.6180469716em;
        right: -.6180469716em;
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        table.cart td.product-remove span.decrease_qty {
            float: none;
            position: relative;
            top: auto;
            right: auto;
            font-size: 1em;
        }
    }
    </style><?php

    // Javascript: Decrease the cart item quantity and update cart
    wc_enqueue_js("$(document.body).on('click', 'span.decrease_qty', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const qtyInput = $(this).closest('tr').find('input.qty');
        qtyInput.attr('value', qtyInput.val()-1);
        $('button[name=\"update_cart\"]').removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
    });");
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested on WooCommerce Storefront theme and work.
You will get something like (where the replaced remove link appears with a minus icon when quantity is more than 1):

You may need to adjust The CSS to match with your web design.
